# How to zip two different sized lists?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to zip 2 lists:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
b = [1,2,3]
```

Result I want is this:

```
[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3],["d"],["e"]]
```

or as you see below, which is the way I want to print the data:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d
e
```

All the different methods I have found and tried, either stop at size of `b`, or start over with `b` again. i.e: `["d",1], ["e",2]`, and that is not what I need.

Comment: I cant see how thats totaly the samen thing, in the other question it talkes about filling multiple tuplets, while here i want to combine 2 lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools

a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

b = [1, 2, 3]
# ans = [list(filter(None, i)) for i in list(itertools.zip_longest(a, b))] 
# list was redundant

a = [list(filter(None, i)) for i in itertools.zip_longest(a, b)]

print(ans)
```

output:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d'], ['e']]
```